# Accessing Global Variables Inside CreateObject

Tags: vba, global-variables

I have the following code within my `ThisWorkbook`

```
Public RawDataSheet As Worksheet
Public UserInputSheet As Worksheet

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Set RawDataSheet = Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set UserInputSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    PopulateCountry

End Sub

Private Sub PopulateCountry()

    LastRow = RawDataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    With RawDataSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        V = .Value
    End With

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .comparemode = 1
        For Each E In V
            If Not .exists(E) Then .Add E, Nothing
        Next
        If .Count Then UserInputSheet.cmbCountry.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
    End With

End Sub
```

My idea is that I want two sheets as global variables to be used anywhere within my code, rather than keep having to type `Sheets("Sheet1")` everywhere.

My problem is that I get an error with:

```
If .Count Then UserInputSheet.cmbCountry.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
```

But this line works fine:

```
If .Count Then Sheets("Sheet1").cmbCountry.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
```

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Replace `Sheets` with `Worksheets`.

Should work then

Comment: Sorry, where do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up changing the `Name` property on the Sheets so I could then refer to it that way.